# How to add fake ClaimsIdentity for testing Asp .Net Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to add some tests for my API. I want to test if for user with bad role Forbidden status code is returned. So far to add fake ClaimsIdentity I were replacing default implementation of IPolicyEvaluator with this one:

```
public class FakePolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
{
    public ClaimsIdentity? ClaimsIdentity { get; set; }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

        if (ClaimsIdentity != null)
        {
            claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(ClaimsIdentity);
        }

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, "test");
        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object? resource)
    {
        var result = PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success();

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

So with this class I could customize ClaimsIdentity by proprty. I am using such attribute

```
[Authorize(Roles="SomeAllowedRole")]
```

which I mark my controller method with. Now it does not work, I guess it's becuase I return AuthenticationResult.Seccess(). Is there any other way to add fake ClaimsIdentity? I were thinking about injecting an original implementation of IPolicyEvaluator to my FakePolicyEvaluator and do something like this:

```
public class FakePolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
{
    private readonly PolicyEvaluator _realPolicyEvaluator;

    public FakePolicyEvaluator(PolicyEvaluator realPolicyEvaluator)
    {
        _realPolicyEvaluator = realPolicyEvaluator;
    }

    public ClaimsIdentity? ClaimsIdentity { get; set; }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

        if (ClaimsIdentity != null)
        {
            claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(ClaimsIdentity);
        }

        context.User = claimsPrincipal;
        return _realPolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, context);
    }

    public Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object? resource)
    {
        return _realPolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(policy, authenticationResult, context, resource);
    }
}
```

But I dont't know how can I register this in my service collection (or create an instance of PolicyEvaluator). Any ideas?

Comment: Something called [Mocking](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-simplify-your-csharp-unit-testing-mocking-framework), you can create a mock of something to fake the data. I would also recommend changing `PolicyEvaluator` to and `Interface`, `IPolicyEvaluator` and injecting that into the class instead of the class it self, allowing you to mock out the `Interface`. If you want an example let me know I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I also see yo don't utilize `Interfaces` please read up on [Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces). Very powerful feature that enables a lot of cool things possible.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand exactly, where I can use mocking here? I don't know if I explained clearly what I want to achive. I want my API not to get ClaimsIdentity from jwt token, but to take an instance created for test.

Comment: In your question you say you want ***Fake*** data. The only way I know to get fake data it to create it yourself, mocking allows you to create fake data. Also whats the point of testing data on a real API? Creating a fake API that works with fake data will allow you to create passing tests at 100% and then you run them against your real API and see what passes and what doesn't, and at that point you will know if you go a bug or not. I've never tested something from API against a real instance that is being used only against fake.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently where in my tests I wanted to fake the authentication but not the authorization.

The solution I used was to call the IAuthorizationService from the AuthorizeAsync method of the IPolicyEvaluator to really check the policy :

```cs
public class FakePolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
{
    public static ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; set; }

    public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
    {
        // fakes the authentication by using a predefined ClaimsIdentity
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

        if (ClaimsIdentity != null)
        {
            claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(ClaimsIdentity);
        }

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, "test");
        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object? resource)
    {
        // Really checks the Authorization by calling the IAuthorizationService
        var authorizationService = context.RequestServices.GetService<IAuthorizationService>();
        var result = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(authenticationResult.Principal, policy);
        return result.Succeeded ? PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success() : PolicyAuthorizationResult.Forbid();

    }
}
```